# How to modify/remove two ArrayLists that are elements in a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, illegalstateexception, concurrentmodification

## Description

I have a `HashMap<ArrayLists<Integer>, <Integer>>`, similar to the following (`{Key=Value}`):

```
{[1]=1, [3]=1, [1, 4, 6]=1, [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]=3, [6]=1}
```

I need to compare and then modify/remove elements in different `ArrayLists` (i.e., elements in the `HashMap`), until the following conditions are met:

1. Each `ArrayList` element only belongs to one list, the list with the highest `Value`.
2. If `Value = 1` for all lists containing that element, then the `ArrayList` element belongs to the singleton list.
3. If an `ArrayList` becomes empty, then it should be removed from the `HashMap`.

Thus for the example above, it should end up with the following:

```
{[1]=1, [4]=1, [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]=3}
```

---

I am used to work with arrays of arrays to do stuff like this. This time it would be practical to have the features of `HashMap` and `ArrayList`, but I am currently not comfortable to do more complicated modification of these data types. I have done several attempts and have had to prevent both [ConcurrentModificationException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/223929/9345990) and [IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6719500/9345990), but have yet to succeed fully. I also have a feeling my implementations are getting unnecessary complex, so I would greatly appreciate to see an implementation by someone experienced with things like this.

---

## A Note About The `HashMap`

The reason I use a `HashMap` (feel free to suggest something more appropriate) is that the `Value` is a count of how many times the `ArrayList` has been "encountered" and added to the `HashMap`.

---

## Minimal Example

Minimal example of my latest non-working (`IndexOutOfBoundsException`) attempt. Note that the creation of the `HashMap` and `ArrayList`s is done statically here since in my real program it is done non-deterministically based on file contents.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<List<Integer>, Integer> example = new HashMap<>(7);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(7);
        list.add(1);
        example.put(list, 1);
        list = new ArrayList<>(7);
        list.add(3);
        example.put(list, 1);
        list = new ArrayList<>(7);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(6);
        example.put(list, 1);
        list = new ArrayList<>(7);
        list.add(0);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);
        example.put(list, 3);
        list = new ArrayList<>(7);
        list.add(6);
        example.put(list, 1);
        System.err.println(example);

        Map<List<Integer>, Integer> copy = new HashMap<>(example);
        for (Map.Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> outer : example.entrySet()) {
            for (Map.Entry<List<Integer>, Integer> inner : copy
                .entrySet()) {
                for (int i : outer.getKey()) {
                    int oSize = outer.getKey().size();
                    int iSize = inner.getKey().size();
                    int oValue = outer.getValue();
                    int iValue = inner.getValue();

                    if (!(inner.equals(outer)) && (inner.getKey()
                        .contains(i))) {
                        if (oSize == 1) {
                            if (oValue < iValue) {
                                outer.getKey().remove(i);
                            } else {
                                inner.getKey().remove(i);
                            }
                        } else if (iSize == 1) {
                            if (iValue < oValue) {
                                outer.getKey().remove(i);
                            } else {
                                inner.getKey().remove(i);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (oValue < iValue) {
                                outer.getKey().remove(i);
                            } else {
                                inner.getKey().remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Could you explain why [3]=1 excluded from the  result?

Comment: @i.bondarenko Due to 1, it should belong to the long list with `Value = 3`.

Comment: Using a mutable value as a key will cause a HashMap to malfunction.  If you modify any of those ArrayLists, you will change their hashCodes, and your HashMap will become corrupt and unreliable.  You must never modify an object which is being used as a key in a HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

Its highly unusual to use an ArrayList as the key to a HashMap ([Are mutable hashmap keys a dangerous practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842049/are-mutable-hashmap-keys-a-dangerous-practice)).
But assuming you are okay with this, to update a Map entry you could remove the entry(both the List and the integer) from the hasmap, create a new List that has your changes, and then reinsert if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about this. Will add a comment about why I use HashMap, feel free to suggest something more appropriate if possible.

Answer (score 2):

In my poor opinion, I suggest order the map value (according to the highest value) in 1st round, then complete our deletion work with business logic.

For example:

```
        Map<List<Integer>, Integer> example = new HashMap<>();
        // data initialize

        // order by Map.Entry::getValue desc
        List<Map.Entry<List<Integer>, Integer>> collect = example.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue() - e1.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // remove duplicate list element in Map.Entry::getKey
        Set<Integer> tmp = new HashSet<>();
        // collect.forEach(c -> c.getKey().removeIf(next -> !tmp.add(next)));
        example = collect
                .stream()
                .filter(c -> {
                    c.getKey().removeIf(next -> !tmp.add(next));
                    return !c.getKey().isEmpty();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Generates the correct answer for this case, will study it further, thank you! What are you reserved about regarding it: "In my poor opinion"?

Comment: Maybe remove in filter is better, it can reduce the times of traversal. (already edited this post)